# List {field2} of entries under a single {field1} when entries have the same {field1}, then move on

Tags: fields, loop, low-alphabet

I'm using Low Alphabet to list songs - so there's a page for A, B, etc. Each page has on average dozens of songs.  The channel type has them broken down into separate fields, so for "Foo (Studio Version)" {song} is "Foo", {version} is "Studio Version", "Foo (Perfecto Mix)" has {song} == "Foo", {version} = "Perfecto Mix", etc. What I'd like to have displayed is (basically) something like:

```
Foo
* Studio Version
* Perfecto Mix
* Live at Somewhere

Bar
* Studio Version
* Wub Wub Remix
```

Where each {version} is displayed under the {song} when the contents of the {song} field match for those entries.

This seems like it should be a fairly straightforward loop for once the contents are sorted, but I'm not having luck. I'm more front-end than scripting, but what I'd be looking for would be something like this in pseudocode:

`* while loop to sort by starting letter (low alphabet wrapper)
* once contents are sorted, iterate through them
* save {song} to a variable {songcheck}, print {version}.
* if next entries {song} == {songcheck} print {version}
* if next entries {song} != {songcheck} rewrite {songcheck} and skip to 3.`

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, as this is more a suggestion: this isn't something Low Alphabet can do out of the box, but I'd recommend looking at Stash for more advanced listings like that.

Comment: Yeah, I've taken a look at stash, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it to loop/nest conditionals yet. I put up the low alphabet connection because I'm not actually serving this through a typical {exp} channel tag in case that made any difference.  I suppose I'd save a stash array of songs that start with foo for each letter, then iterate through that?